# How to switch between threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I have multiple threads running in my script at a time and all the threads needs user's input at the same time, I want to be able to switch between threads so that I can keep track of what input is given to which thread. Actually I would like to interact with a single thread at a time and keep all the other threads on hold until the user specifies which thread he want to interact with.

```
def thr1():
    D=raw_input('>')
    #some code 

def thr2():
    d=raw_input('>')
    #some code

def thr3():
    D=raw_input('>')
    #some code

t1=threading.Thread(target=thr1)
t2=threading.Thread(target=thr2)
t3=threading.Thread(target=thr3)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
```

Now when I run the script it shows
    >
With this I am unable to recognise which thread is it. And if it is t1 i want to keep it and t2 on hold and interact with t3.
How could I do that?

Comment: show us the code, or minimal example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: We can't help you without some context.

Comment: I would recommend to investigate some concurrent programming,  using locks for IO and printing the thread number before the > to differentiate them should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Printing thread numbers is not a problem i can do that i just want to know how to switch between thread